# Most efficient way to store song lyrics in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I need to make an app with 800+ songs and their lyrics. I have a question which would be the most efficient way to store the lyrics and get them as string.
What I'm talking about is should I store them in the string.xml file?
Or a JSON file.
Not sure, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: the best way is to store them in a [sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) dataBase

Comment: If you want a more dynamic option and can guarantee network at some point consider Firebase Firestore (NoSQL BaaS option). You can also Firebase Storage for images (obviously royalty free images or liberally licenced)